# LiveData observer is being triggered multiple times using Navigation Component

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-architecture-navigation, android-mvvm

Scenario: I have two fragments named `FirstFragment` and `UnitFragment`. I go from `FirstFragment` to `UnitFragment` to select a unit to come back to `FirstFragmet` using `navController.popBackStack();` and send unit data to `FirstFragment` which is observing unit data.

This is my `onViewCreated` of `FirstFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (viewModel == null) { // Lazy Initialization
        ApiService apiService = ApiServiceProvider.getInstance();
        AddNewWareViewModelFactory addNewWareViewModelFactory = new AddNewWareViewModelFactory(apiService);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, addNewWareViewModelFactory).get(AddWareViewModel.class);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "OnViewCreated -----> Called");
    viewModel.callNewWare(parentCode);
    viewModel.getNewWareResponse().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
            resObject -> Log.i(TAG, "API Response LiveData Count -----> " + count++)); // Started From Zero

    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) requireActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.container);

    binding.button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
            navController.navigate(FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToUnitFragment());
        }
    });


    if (navHostFragment != null) {
        NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        NavBackStackEntry navBackStackEntry = navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry();
        if (navBackStackEntry != null) {
            SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle = navBackStackEntry.getSavedStateHandle();
            MutableLiveData<Unit> unitLiveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("unit_data");
            unitLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), unit -> binding.tvUnit.setText(unit.getTitle()));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the LogCat result:

```
--- Go to FirstFragment for first time ---
I/FirstFragment: OnViewCreated -----> Called
I/FirstFragment: API Response LiveData Count -----> 0
--- Button clicked to go to UnitFragment to select a unit ---
I/UnitFragment: Selected Unit -----> Meter
--- Come back to FirstFragment ---
I/FirstFragment: OnViewCreated -----> Called
I/FirstFragment: API Response LiveData Count -----> 1
I/FirstFragment: API Response LiveData Count -----> 2
```

As you see in LogCat result, every time I click the button and go to `UnitFragment` and come back to `FirstFragment` the `onViewCreated` will call again and API LiveDataObserver will be triggered TWO times!!!

I know onViewCreated will call again because Navigation Component replaces the fragments instead of adding them. but I don't know why LiveData observer is being triggered two times.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51961333/6444297) but he seems to have ignored Navigation Component.

I need a solution to ...

1. Avoid calling `onViewCreated` codes again.
2. Avoid triggering LiveData observer again.

Comment: Can you please log the value `resValue` being returned from your observer and share those results (i.e. when do you see it change to "Meter")?  Additionally, when updating your `LiveData` object in `UnitFragment` are you using set or post semantics?

Comment: I've mocked the missing parts of your code and it works OK for me. There is no repetitive callings to observers. Make sure your API works as expected and your live data object changes only once when the response received. If this is not the case please provide more details for better help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not the answer to your problems:

> I need a solution to ...
>
> Avoid calling onViewCreated codes again.
>
> Avoid triggering LiveData observer again.

I'm trying to explain about navigation and its behaviors or correct some misunderstandings. These issues have different reasons and `Avoid calling onViewCreated codes again.` is a devious way.

> I know onViewCreated will call again because Navigation Component replaces the fragments instead of adding them.

As you know, replacing fragments when they were added in back-stack, just detaching old fragment from `fragmentManager`. It means the old fragment's **view** will destroy.

And will create its view when you pop *UnitFragment* from the back-stack.

So don't call any API call in `onViewCreated` because it may call multiple times (in configuration changes, destroying fragment, etc...)

It's better to use `onCreate` for initializing non-view-related components (ViewModel + API calls). It reduces `Lazy(!?) Initialization` check.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ApiService apiService = ApiServiceProvider.getInstance();
    AddNewWareViewModelFactory addNewWareViewModelFactory = new AddNewWareViewModelFactory(apiService);
    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this /*owner*/, addNewWareViewModelFactory).get(AddWareViewModel.class);

    viewModel.callNewWare(parentCode);
}
```

And start to observe them in `onViewCreated`. Also, you should consume `unit_data` from navBackStackEntry when you got it.

```
if (navHostFragment != null) {
    NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    NavBackStackEntry navBackStackEntry = navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry();
    if (navBackStackEntry != null) {
        SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle = navBackStackEntry.getSavedStateHandle();
        MutableLiveData<Unit> unitLiveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("unit_data");
        unitLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), unit -> {
            savedStateHandle.remove("unit_data");       // add this line
            return binding.tvUnit.setText(unit.getTitle());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer and for your suggestion about removing savedStateHandle. I think it's better to remove `viewModel.getNewWareResponse().observe(...)` from `onCreate` and put it in `onViewCreated` as you said. Make me happy by an up-vote my compatriot ;)

Comment: We need to pass Activity (`requireActivity()`) instead of Fragment (`this`) to `ViewModelProvider` to be able to share ViewModel data between the Fragments of an Activity. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

`1. Avoid calling onViewCreated codes again`

No, I think you can't avoid that, because your FirstFragment's view destroy when you navigate to other. So it will be call view created again after you come back.

`2. Avoid triggering LiveData observer again.`

You can custom a live data like this:

```kotlin
class SingleLiveEvent<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

  private val pending: AtomicBoolean = AtomicBoolean(false)

  override fun setValue(value: T) {
    pending.set(true)
    super.setValue(value)
  }

  override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
    super.observe(
      owner,
      Observer { value ->
        if (pending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
          observer.onChanged(value)
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

It's just notify to observer when you set a new data.

Comment: It works in this situation but not always. Assume that adding dynamic views is needed according to the API response in `FirstFragment`, dynamic views won't be added when I came back from `UnitFragment` to `FirstFragment`